# Get form recipient from <option> using jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I have form kind of like this:

```
<form method="post" action="processform.php" name="form1">
  <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="email1" />
  <input type="text" />
</form>
```

I want to add a  list containing multiple recipients, like this:

```
<select>
  <option selected="selected">Choose recipient</option>
  <option value="email1">Recipient 1</option>
  <option value="email2">Recipient 2</option>
</select>
```

What is the best way to replace the value of "recipient" by selecting an option from the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either bind a [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event to the select drop down list for auto update of your hidden field.

```
  $("select").change(function(){
      $("input[name=recipient]").val($(this).val());
  });
```

Or your submit event you can assign the hidden field like this:

```
$("input[name=recipient]").val($("select").val());
```

Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p26sC/1/)

Comment: Wow. Super simple. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problem.  If this answer works for you feel free to mark the answer as accepted so others can stumble upon the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=recipient]').val($('select[name=recipient-list]').val());
```